# Acceso a información según roles

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tengo en mi aplicación la siguiente información que viene de un API

```
var info = [
{ userID: 1, name: 'Alex', city: 'Argentina', amount: 50 },
{ userID: 1, name: 'Daniel', city: 'Peru', amount: 20 },
{ userID: 3, name: 'Joaquin', city: 'Guatemala', amount: 30 }
];
```

y tengo la siguiente estructura del modelo User

```
var Users = [
{ userID: 1, adminID: 1, name: 'Gerente1', password: 'sñdlfjalsd', role: 'Gerente' },
{ userID: 2, adminID: 1, name: 'Secretaria1', password: 'qerrqweqr', role: 'Secre' },
{ userID: 3, adminID: 3, name: 'Gerente2', password: 'qerrqweqr', role: 'Gerente' },
]
```

Necesito hacer que la Secretaria (userID 2) tenga acceso unicamente a los siguientes campos creados por el gerente (adminID: 1) al que esta asignada:

```
{ userID: 1, name: 'Alex', city: 'Argentina' },
{ userID: 1, name: 'Daniel', city: 'Peru'},
```

Notese que no incluye el campo "Amount".

Existe algun modulo que pueda utilizar para hacer un Accesos basado en roles de esta forma? cual seria la forma correcta de lograr esta funcionalidad?

Comment: Hola amigo es una pregunta muy ambigua, no has demostrado ningún método ni algún sistema para acceder a esos datos solo has dado los datos en si y una precaria explicación de lo que quieres y por esto se hace esta un poco difícil de entender, te recomiendo que nos brindes un código funcional, completo y verificable o la reproducción del error o lo que no puedes lograr con el método que estés utilizando, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen módulos de rbac para nodeJS, pero te recomiendo codificar tu propio sistema de control de acceso basado en roles con tecnologías de bases de datos con las cuales te sientas cómodo, igual acá te dejo [rbac](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rbac), es un módulo para esto, y ya prefabricado, este trabaja con diferentes tipos de almacenamientos y bases de datos.

El problema en realidad existe cuando ya tienes una estructura de datos preestablecidos, es JSON igual utilizando mongo o similares safas, pero fabricándolo por tu cuenta tienes una mejor percepción de como se están procesando tus datos.

> Por ultima hasta una sencilla función podría servirte, te dejo un
>   ejemplo.

Para esto necesitas crear un nivel de acceso desde que se introduce o se almacena el usuario, por ejemplo creamos en nuestro objeto una llave para almacenar este valor:

```
{ userID: 1, adminID: 1, access: 1, name: 'Gerente1', password: 'sñdlfjalsd', role: 'Gerente' }
```

En este caso `access: 1`, podríamos tener varios niveles jerárquicos, por ejemplo del 4 al 1.

Ahora lo utilizamos para diferenciar entre usuarios y dictaminar que clase de usuarios pueden trabajar con los datos:

```js
//Datos del dom

var drop = document.getElementById("drop");
var get = document.getElementById("get");

//Información con niveles de acceso permitido

var info = [
{ userID: 1, access: 1, name: 'Alex', city: 'Argentina', amount: 50 },
{ userID: 1, access: 1, name: 'Daniel', city: 'Peru', amount: 20 },
{ userID: 3, access: 3, name: 'Joaquin', city: 'Guatemala', amount: 30 
},
{ userID: 2, access: 2, name: 'Alexandra', city: 'España', amount: 60 },
{ userID: 1, access: 3, name: 'Juan', city: 'Venezuela', amount: 30 },
];

var Users = [
 { userID: 1, access: 1, adminID: 1, name: 'Gerente1', password: 'sñdlfjalsd', role: 'Gerente' },
 { userID: 1, access: 2, adminID: 2, name: 'SubG', password: 'sñdlfjalsd', role: 'Sub-Gerente' },
{ userID: 2, access: 3, adminID: 1, name: 'Secretaria1', password: 'qerrqweqr', role: 'Secre' },
{ userID: 3, access: 1, adminID: 3, name: 'Gerente2', password: 'qerrqweqr', role: 'Gerente' },
{ userID: 1, access: 4, adminID: 4, name: 'UsuarioX', password: 'sñdlfjalsd', role: 'Usuario' }
]

var valueBlackList = ["amount","money","balance","credit"];

//Función para clasificar la data segun el nivel del usuario.

function getData(access, info, cb) {
  switch (access) {
    case 1:
      return cb(info);
      break;
    case 2:
      var newInfo = [];
      for (var i=0;i<info.length;i++){
        if(info[i].access >= 2) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(info[i]));
          for (var j=0;j<valueBlackList.length;j++){
            var current = valueBlackList[j];
            delete obj[current];
           }
          newInfo.push(obj);
        }
      }
      return cb(newInfo);
      break;
    case 3:
      var newInfo = [];
      for (var i=0;i<info.length;i++){
        if(info[i].access >= 3) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(info[i]));
          for (var j=0;j<valueBlackList.length;j++){
            var current = valueBlackList[j];
            delete obj[current];
           }
          newInfo.push(obj);
        }
      }
      return cb(newInfo);
      break;
    default:
      var error = {code:404,message:"Acceso insuficiente."}
      return cb(error)
      break;
  }
}

// Interacciones con el dom.

for (var i=0;i<Users.length;i++) {
  drop.innerHTML += "<option value="+Users[i].access+">"+Users[i].name+"</option>";
}

drop.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  console.clear();
  console.log("Usuario de nivel "+this.value);
});

get.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var level = drop.value;
  level = parseInt(level);
  getData(level, info, function(data){
    document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

select {
  width: 250px;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  padding:6px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

pre {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<h1>Seleccione el usuario para obtener datos:</h1>
<select id="drop">
</select>

<button id="get">Obtener Data</button>

<pre>Esperando consulta...<pre>
```

Ya después podemos crear filtros whitelists y muchas cosas para diferenciar y clasificar los datos según el nivel de acceso que tenga el usuario, espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

> EDIT:

He agregado un filtro para que puedas crear un lista con los que los usuarios de menos nivel no puedan ver ciertos datos (Ya implementado en el ejemplo de arriba):

```
var valueBlackList = ["amount","money","balance","credit"];
for (var i=0;i<valueBlackList.length;i++){
  var current = valueBlackList[i];
  delete info[current];
}
```

Como ves ahora puedes ocultar información nada mas agregando el nombre del valor de la información enviada por la api y que no quieres darle al usuario de menor nivel.

Por ultimo, recomiendo hacer un nivel de acceso jerárquico como te lo he mostrado en lugar de que un usuario pueda utilizar datos de soloun usuario, de  resto podrías crear listas negras y blancas para filtrar este tipo de cosas, como en el ejemplo, ya sea con usuarios, datos, etc.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.